# How to show a warning or bar  from BHO in Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, add-on, ieaddon

I'd like to display a warning on some websites, similar to the warning IE shows when it blocks an ActiveX.

[image: IE warning]

Or a bar (not a tool bar) like Google Translate (from the Google Toolbar):

[image]

I'm trying to do this in C# in a Browser Helper Object. Any code sample, or reference on the subject?

**UPDATE**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985725/is-there-an-ie-notification-box-like-gbrowser-getnotificationbox-in-firefox) explains how to do it in C++, but I cannot figure out how to translate this into C#

Answer (score 3):

The Information Band (and it's successor notification UI) is not extensible.  Faking it is also frowned upon.  You could inject JS+HTML into the page to mimic it, however.

Comment: Thanks. I add to do the same in Chrome/Safari/Opera, but using the native warning like in Firefox would have been preferable